# Erro "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Tags: c#

Estou desenvolvendo um serviço do Windows que instala normal, mas toda vez que o inicio, ele acusa o seguinte erro:

> PCService Error on: 15/12/2016 10:53:13  Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto.
>   em DataLayer.Repository.ConfigRobotRepository.FindByName(String name)
>   em RSPC.PCService.ScheduleService() at line 0

Já revirei o código e fiz vários testes, mas não consigo entender qual objeto ele não está encontrando. Seguem os códigos:

```
ConfigRobotRepository.FindByName

    public ConfigRobot FindByName(string name)
            {
                using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
                {
                    ConfigRobot config = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(ConfigRobot))
                        .Add(Restrictions.Like("Name", name))
                        .UniqueResult<ConfigRobot>();
                    return config;
                }
            }
```

ScheduleService()

```
    try
        {
            foreach (var schedular in schedulars)
            {
                //Get from database mode from this key (example = "PregoeiroChama")
                ConfigRobot config = ConfigRobotController.FindByName(schedular.Key);
                DateTime scheduleTime = DateTime.MinValue;

                if (config.Mode.ToUpper().Equals(ConfigRobotController.Interval))
                {
                    //Get from database interval from this key (example = "PregoeiroChama)
                    int intervalMin = (int)config.IntervalMin;
                    scheduleTime = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(intervalMin);
                }
                else if (config.Mode.ToUpper().Equals(ConfigRobotController.Daily))
                {
                    //Get from database daily hour from this key (example = "PreogeiroChama")
                    int hour = (int)config.ScheduleTime;

                    if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= hour)
                    {
                        DateTime now = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
                        scheduleTime = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, hour, 0, 0);
                    }
                    else
                        scheduleTime = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, hour, 0, 0);
                }

                TimeSpan timeSpan = scheduleTime.Subtract(DateTime.Now);

                config.NextDate = scheduleTime;
                config.Status = 'W';

                /*Log*/
                string schedule = string.Format("{0} day(s) {1} hours {2} minutes", timeSpan.Days, timeSpan.Hours, timeSpan.Minutes);
                Log("PCService schedule " + config.Name + " to run after: " + schedule + " {0}", Path.GetTempPath() + config.Name + ".txt");

                long dueTime = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalMilliseconds);
                schedular.Value.Change(dueTime, Timeout.Infinite);

                ConfigRobotRepository repo = new ConfigRobotRepository();
                repo.Update(config);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.StackTrace trace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(e, true);
            var frame = trace.GetFrame(0);
            var line = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
            Log("PCService Error on: {0} " + e.Message + e.StackTrace + " at line " + line, Path.GetTempPath() + "PCService" + ".txt");
            using (var service = new ServiceController("PCService"))
            {
                service.Stop();
            }
        }
```

O que devo fazer para corrigir este erro ?

Comment: Debugue e descubra qual a linha onde ocorre o erro.

Comment: Você verificou se a instância config da classe ConfigRobot está recebendo um objeto através do método ConfigRobotController.FindByName(schedular.Key)?

Comment: Cara debuga o código e vê qual objeto está nullo.

No foearch pode ser o "schedulars", pode ser o método openSession() que não esteja funcionando e consequentemente não populando a session e quando vc vai usar a session dá pau.

Várias possibilidades...

Comment: `NHibernateHelper` foi você que criou, certo?

Comment: @jbueno sim, é a classe que configura o NHibernate

Comment: E esse método `OpenSession()` funciona? Você usa ele em outros lugares?